# Use regexmatch to determine if one cell's content contains another's

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I want use a cell in regexmatch as regular_expression parameter.
My goal is to draw green background for A1 if B1 contains A1 inside of it. How to do this with regexmatch?

Comment: Please add more details. By the way, did you already read the help article about [regexmatch](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have added comments

Comment: It's still unclear what you're after. Could you perhaps provide some sample data and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting with the option for `custom function`:

```
=IF(ISTEXT($A$1:$A),REGEXMATCH($A$1:$A,$B$1:$B),)
```

[image]